# How can we save a user uploaded file to a specific location (eg: /temp/testfolder/) in IBM BPM v8.6.1

Tags: ibm-bpm, ecm

I am trying to save user uploaded files to a specific location using "ECM File Uploader" & "ECM Document List" in IBM BPM v8.6.1. Currently user is uploading files through an interface and document store is providing a reference URL to the file(s) that are uploaded but not able to store the files at a specific location(/temp/testfolder/).

Would be great if someone can provide pointers about achieving this. Are there any in-build features which help?

Thanks.

IBM BPM store user uploaded files to a specific location.